# Добавление существующего метода

Tags: android, java

Для работы мне нужен метод drawPath (Path path, Paint paint). Импортировал все, что только можно было. Добавил метод в свой интерфейс, после чего в классе просит добавить этот метод. После добавления вижу это:

```
@Override
public void drawPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Нету даже super в методе. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог спокойно воспользоваться методом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наследоваться от класса Canvas. Именно в нём есть такой метод. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
    public void a(){

    }
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void a(){
        super.a();
    }
}
```